# html/css breaking multicolumn text

Tags: javascript, html, css

i looking for solution for this situation: i have large html text in one div container. I using css3 multicolumns on that. And I would like to breaks this container after contant height. So I would a n this same heights "tables" with multicolumn layouts. I'ts similar to newspaper - large block text breaking after page height - next page is continuing previous page text with the same multicolumn layout... how can i do it ?

Comment: Show us the code.  It should be as simple as setting a width.

Comment: i haven't yet code ;) it was theoretical question ;)